# LINQ to SQL, in memory lists and anonymous types

Tags: linq-to-sql, anonymous-types

I am joining a table to an in memory list and wanting to create an anonymous type from the results. I have joined the 2 data sources together ok, but I'm not sure of the syntax required to use a property from the in memory list in the anonymous type.

Here's my code

```
        public DataKeys(IEnumerable<Element> elements)
    {
        var defsource = new DefinitionSource();
        var items = from def in defsource.Definitions
                    where elements.Select(el=> el.Value).Contains(def.Name)                        
                    select new { def.Key };
        ...

    }
```

(Obviously "elements" is an in-memory list of element and "DefinitionSource" is a wrapper around a table.) This works fine, but as you can see there is no property from the in-memory list of elements. I've tried this

```
      var items = from def in defsource.Definitions
                  where elements.Select(el=> el.Value).Contains(def.Name)  
                  from el in elements
                  where el.Value.Equals(def.Name)
                  select new { el.NodeType, def.Key };
```

but at run time it gens a "{"Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."}"

So what is the syntax I need to do this?

Many thx IA

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
var def=defsource.Definitions
                    .Where(a=>elements.Select(el=>el.Value).Contains(a.Name))
                    .ToList();
var items = from d in def
          from el in elements
            .Where(a=>a.Value==d.Name)
                  select new { el.NodeType, d.Key };
```

Comment: thx but no ... it didn't. Looks the same as my own only without the query syntax.

Comment: Sorry about that. Update the answer

Answer (score 1):

To query over two data sources both of them needs to be in memory are both of them should be in database. you can do the following to achieve the results you want

```
var query = (from def in defsource.Definitions
                  where elements.Select(el=> el.Value).Contains(def.Name)  
                  ).ToList();//bring filtered result in memory
var Items = from def in query //Definitions are already filtered no need to re-apply where
            from el in elements.Where(a=>a.Value == def.Name)
            select new {el.NodeType, def.Key};
```

Comment: Thx vm. Helpful. Just needed a select def in the initial query.